# Alfresco 3.4.d community warnings/errors related to standard.jar on jboss 6

Tags: alfresco, jboss6.x

I am trying to get alfresco community 3.4.d to work on jboss 6.1.0.Final but I am having some issues. To keep this question to one problem I am interested in what would cause this warning and how to fix it. It appears there is a URL inside a file inside of standard.jar that is referencing a URL with spaces in it. Not sure why this is not an issue in older versions of jboss and is in jboss 6? Is jboss 6 stricter about these kind of things? Can any one shed light on this?

```
16:50:33,112 WARN  [SaxJBossXBParser] SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd' must have even number of URI's. @ vfs:///home/james/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/alfresco.war/WEB-INF/lib/standard.jar/META-INF/scriptfree.tld[7,19]
16:50:33,113 WARN  [JBossEntityResolver] Trying to resolve systemId as a non-file URL: vfs:///home/james/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/alfresco.war/WEB-INF/lib/standard.jar/META-INF/web
16:50:33,114 WARN  [SaxJBossXBParser] schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'web', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>. @ vfs:///home/james/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/alfresco.war/WEB-INF/lib/standard.jar/META-INF/scriptfree.tld[7,19]
16:50:33,122 WARN  [JBossEntityResolver] Trying to resolve systemId as a non-file URL: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
16:51:33,595 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfs:///home/james/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/alfresco.war state=PreParse mode=Manual requiredState=Parse: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfs:///home/james/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/alfresco.war
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:383) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:343) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:315) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.deploy(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:255) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: vfs:///home/james/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/alfresco.war/WEB-INF/lib/standard.jar/META-INF/scriptfree.tld@7,19
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:224) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:178) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:257) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:231) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:137) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployment.TldParsingDeployer.parse(TldParsingDeployer.java:64) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployment.TldParsingDeployer.parse(TldParsingDeployer.java:38) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:121) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.handleMultipleFiles(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:446) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:319) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:376) [:2.2.2.GA]
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: Failed to parse schema for nsURI=http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee, localName=taglib, schemaLocation=web
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.resolver.AbstractMutableSchemaResolver.resolve(AbstractMutableSchemaResolver.java:350) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.SundayContentHandler.startElement(SundayContentHandler.java:176) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.startElement(SaxJBossXBParser.java:401) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.startElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:209) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: -1:-1 -1:-1 schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinderTerminatingErrorHandler.handleError(XsdBinderTerminatingErrorHandler.java:40) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.reportDOMFatalError(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XSLoaderImpl.load(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.Util.loadSchema(Util.java:394) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinder.bind(XsdBinder.java:178) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinder.bind(XsdBinder.java:149) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.resolver.AbstractMutableSchemaResolver.resolve(AbstractMutableSchemaResolver.java:342) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    ... 72 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this has to do something with: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8268

I guess they are saying to use 6.1.0.

---

Update: according to a French [forum](http://deptmedia.cnam.fr/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=8005&view=next) the JSTL library is old and should be version 1.1.2

Comment: Thanks for that link. Actually I am using 6.1.0.Final. I read over that ticket and it appears that some one posed basically the same log/console messages as me and some one else replied that it was not the same issue and that it was a schema validation one.

Comment: Yep I did read that, but wasn't sure. I mean you can't fully trust support guys ;) And I thought maybe you were still on 6.0.

Comment: And, according to the post, you could also switch of validation, have you tried that?

Comment: I was never able to find the config file that allows me to switch off validation.

Comment: I tried updating the JSTL library but then I just run into the same issue on another tld file. I guess I could update that library also. I just get an uneasy feeling changing things inside a war file. I did finally find that flag to switch off validation (server/default/deployers/jbossweb.deployers/META-INF/war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml then under the TldParsingDeployer bean add <property name="useSchemaValidation">false</property>). That flag appears to change nothing for me.

Comment: Since version JSTL 1.2.x there is only 1 jar file, not jstl.jar & standard.jar, just jstl.jar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3268/discussion-between-tahir-malik-and-startoftext)